# (node:9263) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: ideas validation failed: imageUrl: Path `imageUrl` is required

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, multer

I'm running into `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError validation failed: imageUrl: Path`imageUrl`is required` whenever the user wants to upload image, but when I remove/comment the `required: true` keyword on the models file under my imageUrl section I can submit the post but the image would not be uploaded on the file system and it wont render so I will just see the title and the details of the submitted post, my development environment is
`Debian 9.9, express": "^4.17.1, multer": "^1.4.0, mongoose": "^5.6.3, MongoDB v4.0.11, node v10.16.1 listed below is my code from app.js, model.js, routes.js and add.handlebars(view)` respectively. Your help is highly appriciated

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const multer = require('multer');

const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);

//const app = express();

// Load routes
const ideas = require('./routes/ideas');
const users = require('./routes/users');

// Passport Config
require('./config/passport')(passport);
// DB Config
const db = require('./config/database');

// Map global promise - get rid of warning
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
// Connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect(db.mongoURI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true
})
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

  // image handling on db 

  const app = express();
const store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: db.mongoURI,
  collection: 'sessions'
});

const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'images');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + '-' + file.originalname);
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
    file.mimetype === 'image/png' ||
    file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' ||
    file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg'
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

// Handlebars Middleware
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
  defaultLayout: 'main'
}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Static folder
app.use(
  multer({ storage: fileStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).single('image')
);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));

// Method override middleware
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

// Express session midleware
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: true,
 saveUninitialized: true
}));

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

// Global variables
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});

// Index Route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const title = 'Welcome';
  res.render('index', {
    title: title
  });
});

// About Route
app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.render('about');
});

// Use routes
app.use('/ideas', ideas);
app.use('/users', users);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () =>{
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

for my models I have two files Idea.js and User.js listed below respectively just in case

models/Idea.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const IdeaSchema = new Schema({
  title:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  imageUrl: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  details:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  user:{
    type: String,
    required:true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

mongoose.model('ideas', IdeaSchema);
```

models/User.js (just in case)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

and for the route I have two files ideas.js & users.js posted below respectively

route/ideas.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const router = express.Router();
const {ensureAuthenticated} = require('../helpers/auth');

// Load Idea Model
require('../models/Idea');
const Idea = mongoose.model('ideas');

// Idea Index Page
router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  Idea.find({user: req.user.id})
    .sort({date:'desc'})
    .then(ideas => {
      res.render('ideas/index', {
        ideas:ideas
      });
    });
});

// Add Idea Form
router.get('/add', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render('ideas/add');
});

// Edit Idea Form
router.get('/edit/:id', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  Idea.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id
  })
  .then(idea => {
    if(idea.user != req.user.id){
      req.flash('error_msg', 'Not Authorized');
      res.redirect('/ideas');
    } else {
      res.render('ideas/edit', {
        idea:idea
      });
    }

  });
});

// Process Form
router.post('/', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  let errors = [];

  if(!req.body.title){
    errors.push({text:'Please add a title'});
  }
  if(!req.body.details){
    errors.push({text:'Please add some details'});
  }

  if(errors.length > 0){
    res.render('/add', {
      errors: errors,
      title: req.body.title,
      details: req.body.details
    });
  } else {
    const newUser = {
      title: req.body.title,
      details: req.body.details,
      user: req.user.id
    }
    new Idea(newUser)
      .save()
      .then(idea => {
        req.flash('success_msg', 'Video idea added');
        res.redirect('/ideas');
      })
  }
});

// Edit Form process
router.put('/:id', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  Idea.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id
  })
  .then(idea => {
    // new values
    idea.title = req.body.title;
    idea.details = req.body.details;

    idea.save()
      .then(idea => {
        req.flash('success_msg', 'Video idea updated');
        res.redirect('/ideas');
      })
  });
});

// Delete Idea
router.delete('/:id', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  Idea.remove({_id: req.params.id})
    .then(() => {
      req.flash('success_msg', 'Video idea removed');
      res.redirect('/ideas');
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

users.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');
const router = express.Router();

// Load User Model
require('../models/User');
const User = mongoose.model('users');

// User Login Route
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('users/login');
});

// User Register Route
router.get('/register', (req, res) => {
  res.render('users/register');
});

// Login Form POST
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect:'/ideas',
    failureRedirect: '/users/login',
    failureFlash: true
  })(req, res, next);
});

// Register Form POST
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  let errors = [];

  if(req.body.password != req.body.password2){
    errors.push({text:'Passwords do not match'});
  }

  if(req.body.password.length < 4){
    errors.push({text:'Password must be at least 4 characters'});
  }

  if(errors.length > 0){
    res.render('users/register', {
      errors: errors,
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
      password2: req.body.password2
    });
  } else {
    User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
      .then(user => {
        if(user){
          req.flash('error_msg', 'Email already regsitered');
          res.redirect('/users/register');
        } else {
          const newUser = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
          });

          bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
            bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
              if(err) throw err;
              newUser.password = hash;
              newUser.save()
                .then(user => {
                  req.flash('success_msg', 'You are now registered and can log in');
                  res.redirect('/users/login');
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  console.log(err);
                  return;
                });
            });
          });
        }
      });
  }
});

// Logout User
router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  req.flash('success_msg', 'You are logged out');
  res.redirect('/users/login');
});

module.exports = router;
```

and my view/addview

```
<div class="card card-body">
  <h3>Video Idea</h3>
  <form action="/ideas" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
                <label for="image">Image</label>
                <input 
                    type="file" 
                    name="image" 
                    id="image" >
            </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="details">Details</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="details" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to extract the value from image input.
First of all Multer works with a form with `multipart/form-data`, that is:

```
<form action="/ideas" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
```

Once you edited that, in `route/ideas.js` wherever in your middlewares you check and extract

```
title: req.body.title,
details: req.body.details
```

check and extract image input too, that is:

> imageUrl: **req.file.path**

Comment: Thank's your a star! it works,  I need to pay more attention to details :)